# How can I rotate the gun barrel around it self but also to other directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make that the gun barrel is shooting around like out of control.

What I did so far is that the gun barrel will rotate around it self since I want to make it shooting while losing control but now how do I make it to rotate also on x and z so it will shoot all around ?

[image: gun barrel]

The script is attached to the parent Drone and now I'm rotating the gun barrel on Y only.
But I also want it to be rotate on X and Z so will shoot all around the place and not only forward.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] wings;
    public Transform[] propellers;
    public Transform gunBarrel;
    public float propellersSpinSpeed = 50;
    public float wingsSpinSpeed = 50;
    public float gunBarrelSpeed = 50;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < propellers.Length; i++)
        {
            propellers[i].Rotate(0, propellersSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < wings.Length; i++)
        {
            wings[i].Rotate(0, wingsSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        gunBarrel.Rotate(0, 30 * gunBarrelSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the script I'm rotating the barrel on the Y. How can I make it now realistic by rotating the barrel also on x and z so it will shoot all around the place ? (The shooting part I will do later first I want to make the rotations).

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be to simply randomize the values of the rotation:

```
public float gunBarrelSpeed = 10;
private void Update()
{
    float xRotation = Random.value;
    float yRotation = Random.value;
    float zRotation = Random.value;

    xRotation *= speed;
    yRotation *= speed;
    zRotation *= speed;
    gunBarrel.Rotate(xRotation, yRotation, zRotation);
}
```

Maybe you'll have to put some boundaries (cause I suppouse the gun will have it someone), but the idea is the same.